# google play transfering data via link to app

Tags: web, google-play, data-management

[context part]  I am currently on vacation in austria, and decided to buy some tickets for the zoo in insbruck. After typing in my data... a link to their app in the google play store. And after downloading it, google play didnt show the usual open button, to open the app, rather it showed a button saying "continue" and after clicking it, the app opened with my data already in place

so here is my question: how may they have done it, and how can i implement it in my own app / website

thanks a lot in advance, would be nice if there was a easy way of doing this

EDIT: idk, may they have shared the session-token somehow, used the ip of my mobile?

Comment: you can refer AppLinkAssist : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

[image]

this is done by [Add an intent filter for deep links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#add-an-intent-filter-for-deep-links)

> As with plain deep links, you must add a new intent filter to the activity that handles deep links for your app. The intent filter should catch deep links of your domain, since the Dynamic Link will redirect to your domain if your app is installed. This is required for your app to receive the Dynamic Link data after it is installed/updated from the Play Store and one taps on **Continue button**. In AndroidManifest.xml: